# calling CUDA compiled .dll from R

Tags: c, r, cuda

I am using Windows 7 platform.

I describe below step-by-step all the routines that I perform to get the .dll file (PASS), dyn.load it in R (PASS) and evoking .Call function in R (FAIL).

When evoking .Call I get:

```
> out<- .Call("rowAND", as.integer(t(m)), nrow(m), ncol(m))
**Error in .Call("rowAND", as.integer(t(m)), nrow(m), ncol(m)) : 
  C symbol name "rowAND" not in load table**
```

1) Below the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

#include "cuPrintf.cuh"
#include "cuPrintf.cu"

#include "cuRow.h"
#include "cuError.h"

extern "C" { 
SEXP rowAND(SEXP x, SEXP r_nrow, SEXP r_ncol) {
    // input: 
    //              x=as.integer(t(m)), vector of integer values from R (t(m) because store values by col)
    //              r_nrow=nrow(m), scalar
    //              r_ncol=ncol(m), scalar

    //x = coerceVector(x, INTSXP); // force coercion to a matrix of real values

    // define deimension
    int nrow = asInteger(r_nrow);
    int ncol = asInteger(r_ncol);
    size_t m_size;
    size_t calc_size;
    m_size = nrow * ncol * sizeof(int); // m (input)
    calc_size = nrow * sizeof(int); // change to nrow/ncol depending on calculation (output)

    // R
    SEXP r;
    PROTECT(r = allocMatrix(INTSXP,nrow,1));

    // cuda error variable
    cudaError_t err;

    // allocate HOST 
    int *h_m = INTEGER(x);
    int *h_calc = INTEGER(r);

    // allocate DEVICE
    int *d_m = NULL, *d_calc = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_m, m_size); checkError(err);
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_calc, calc_size); checkError(err);

    // copy host matrix to device
    err = cudaMemcpy(d_m, h_m, m_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); checkError(err);

    // Initialize cuPrintf -- DEBUGGING
    cudaPrintfInit();

    dim3 numBlocks(nrow,1,1); // blocks
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(1,1,1); // 1 thread per block
    rowOR<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock,0,0>>>(d_m, d_calc, ncol); // main call

    // Terminate cuPrintf -- DEBUGGING
    cudaPrintfDisplay (stdout, true);
    cudaPrintfEnd ();

    err = cudaGetLastError(); checkError(err);

    // Copy the device result vector in device memory to the host result vector
    err = cudaMemcpy(h_calc, d_calc, calc_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); checkError(err);

    // Free device global memory
    err = cudaFree(d_m); checkError(err);
    err = cudaFree(d_calc); checkError(err);

    // Reset the device
    err = cudaDeviceReset();

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return r;
}
```

2) I compile .cu file, using nvcc which generates the object (.obj). Thus, I link the libraries (PASS), no problem here, and it generates .dll file.

3) when I load the .dll using the R command: dyn.load **IT PASS**.
The loaded .dll appears in `getLoadedDLLs()`:

```
> getLoadedDLLs()
                                                                                  Filename Dynamic.Lookup
base                                                                                  base          FALSE
methods       C:/Revolution/R-Community-6.2/R-2.15.3/library/methods/libs/i386/methods.dll          FALSE
Revobase    C:/Revolution/R-Community-6.2/R-2.15.3/library/Revobase/libs/i386/Revobase.dll           TRUE
tools             C:/Revolution/R-Community-6.2/R-2.15.3/library/tools/libs/i386/tools.dll          FALSE
grDevices C:/Revolution/R-Community-6.2/R-2.15.3/library/grDevices/libs/i386/grDevices.dll          FALSE
stats             C:/Revolution/R-Community-6.2/R-2.15.3/library/stats/libs/i386/stats.dll          FALSE
cuRow           C:/Users/msn/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/R_C/R_C/Debug/cuRow.dll           TRUE
```

4) **HERE COMES THE PROBLEM:** When I check if the function rowAND is loaded I get **FALSE**:

```
> is.loaded("rowAND")
[1] FALSE
>
```

Thus, obviously, it fails when I run .Call (because it is not loaded):

```
> path.dll<-'C:/Users/msn/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/R_C/R_C/Debug'
> dyn.load(file.path(path.dll,paste0("cuRow", .Platform$dynlib.ext)))
> nrow<-10
> ncol<-3
> m<-matrix(sample(c(0,1),nrow*ncol,replace=TRUE),nrow,ncol)
> out<- .Call("rowAND", as.integer(t(m)), nrow(m), ncol(m))
Error in .Call("rowAND", as.integer(t(m)), nrow(m), ncol(m)) : 
  C symbol name "rowAND" not in load table
```

I see that the function appears to be correctly defined in the source code, but it can't be "seen" in the loaded library.

What I am missing here? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Based on @Dirk partial answer, will try to write a CUDA dll project which will be called by C. Thus, I can compile the target C source using standard R CMD SHLIB.

like: C (dll), deployed to R which calls CUDA dll inside.

will update when done!

**EDIT 2:**

I answered my own question below. I finally could get `CUDA` implementation in `R` (`WINDOWS platform`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to post an answer to my own question, for those who are experiencing the same difficulties. I can categorize the answer as a workaround to the problem.

End of day, my problem was to implement `CUDA` `GPU` parallelism in `R` using `WINDOWS` platform.

I see that the majority of `CRAN` packages (not to say all) implementing `CUDA` have NO binaries for WINDOWS platform. In other words, if you try to build from source in `WINDOWS` it fails. I guess they haven't been built for WINDOWS because it is trick to compile and link .cu files in `WINDOWS` using `MinGW` and `nvcc` compiler together.

NVidia has VS2010 as the main platform for `WINDOWS` development, and eclipse plug-in is only supported for Linux. Although, nvcc compiler supports `-ccbin` option which can make it call `gcc`, to configure the "toolchain" is really trick.

My workaround was to develop a DLL project in VS2010, and to compile and link the DLL using `VS2010` native compiler/linker which is `cl`.

This dll is the piece that internally calls the `CUDA GPU` parallelism.

After compiled in `VS2010`, I loaded the dll using `dyn.load()` and called its functions using `.C` in `R`.

It finally worked, and end of day I could deploy `CUDA` `GPU` parallelism functionality to `R` in a `WINDOWS` platform.

I could deploy the same .dll in a package, using NAMESPACE, and provide the dll source code inside the CRAN tar ball, aiming not to infringe open source policies. Anyways, it is a workaround.

Two important factors:

1) To deploy all exported functions in native C, using `extern "C"`.

2) To consider all input variables of the functions as pointers, since it is mandatory when using '.C' calls.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do in your case is to look *very closely* at the existing R package for CUDA which are publicly available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) as they provide working implementations. I believe at least some of these build on Windows too.

Among the CRAN packages using CUDA are

- [gputools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/index.html)
- [cudaBayesreg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cudaBayesreg/index.html)
- [WideLM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WideLM/index.html)

and more. See the [CRAN Task View on High-Performance Computing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) for more.

I am most familiar with the first (and oldest) one.  I uses one layer of code to call from R to C, and then another to call from C to the CUDA-enabled code compiled with NVidia's compiler frontend.  The last one uses Rcpp for the passage from R to C/C++.  I suspect your error is due to trying to skip one step.

Comment: Dirk, first of all thanks a lot for your prompt response. I see previous pots, you saying that the problem was NOT using extern C, so C++ complains. Just in case, am I using extern C directive in my source .cu file in a correct way?

Comment: I almost always use `.Call()` -- and as I said, if I were you I'd look at **existing working examples** first.  Just rebuilding one of those packages will do you good to prove you have the toolchain right.  Then drop in your code.

Comment: Ah, sorry, was absent minded. You said `extern "C"` where I read `.C()`. My bad.  Rest of comment stands though :) -- working minimal examples first.  At the end of the day you need to be able to write a piece of C code that can call into CUDA. Then wrap that for R as usual.  C++ is fine as long as you maintain the **C-level** interface provided by R.

Answer (score 1):

There are several important things when compile R with CUDA by Visual Studio on Windows.

1. Declare the C function with **__declspec(dllexport)** keyword (install of **extern "C"** )

   ```
   extern “C” __declspec(dllexport)
   ```
2. Build the same version with R (32- or 64-bits); Otherwise, loading DLL in R will fail by:

> Load Library failure: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

3. Include CUDA library in Visual Studio correctly. In general, it will be added in :

> Solution Explorer → Project name

[image]

> Properties → Linker → Input → Additional Dependencies

[image]

Other detail steps, you can refer **[NVIDIA blog](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/accelerate-r-applications-cuda/) and [ParallelR](http://www.parallelr.com).**